# Error al Ejecutar un query nativo en ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, stored-procedure

Buenas a todos estoy ejecutando un procedure en mi proyecto pero me esta retornando un null y no esta reconociendo el dato que ingreso en mi variable de entrada , por eso me esta retornado null , o que error estoy cometiendo , quiero consumir desde mi navegador y devuelve este error ,¿ en qué estoy fallando? qué significa ese error

este es mi servicio

```
[HttpGet("prueba/{@id}")]
        public ActionResult prueba(string id)
        {
            var blogs = _context.AfccaLiquidacions
            .FromSqlRaw("@EXECUTE amb_valida_Carga  where @id={id}")
             .ToList();

            return Ok(blogs);
        }
```

este es el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la ruta que ingreso al ejecutar es

```
https://localhost:44359/api/Login/prueba/D08
```

Comment: amb_valida_Carga   es un procedimiento? y si es así que valores espera.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea id_vendedro

Comment: intenta con `.FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE amb_valida_Carga @id_vendedor = {id}")`

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet("prueba/{@id}")]
    public ActionResult prueba(string id)
    {
        var blogs = _context.AfccaLiquidacions
        .FromSqlRaw("@EXECUTE amb_valida_Carga  where @id={id}")
         .ToList();

        return Ok(blogs);
    }
```

Debe ser por que no estas retornando un entero

```
[HttpGet("prueba/{@id}")]
    public int prueba(string id)
    {
        blogs = _context.AfccaLiquidacions
        .FromSqlRaw("@EXECUTE amb_valida_Carga  where @id={id}")
         .ToList();

        return blogs;
    }
```